# Preview of attachments already added to a case?

Tags: apex, community, visual-workflow, case, attachment

Can we have a preview of the attachments already added to a case?

In other words, if we do 1 attachment and then want to add another, can we see in a small section which one has already been uploaded?

Below is a series of Screenshots that outline the functionality that I am looking for.

1. I upload a file to the case and click DONE

[image]

2. When I click done I am brought back to an empty attachments screen.

[image]

Is there any way for me to see what attachments I have uploaded to the case?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom component for attaching 'Files' (attachments can't be previewed).
In that you can list the files already attached to the case which will have preview button.
After attaching the file one can click on the preview button next to it.
Please also note that salesforce can't preview all types of files.